# Происхождение слова "брюзжать"

Tags: этимология

Задумалась о слове "брюзжать" — а от какого корня оно происходит?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как воспринимается речь брюзги для слушателя? *Бу-бу бубубу бубу...* по всей видимости от звукоподражания появилось и это слово. Фасмер считает тоже самое.